# Вращение объекта вокруг точки

Tags: графика, 2d

Нужно повернуть объект вокруг зеленой точки на угол от -PI до PI. Как это можно сделать, с учетом того, что ось координат начинается сверху? Координаты красной точки: (x1,y1), зеленой: (x2,y2)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Объект представлен координатами углов?

Comment: Скорее всего ваш объект задан не одной красной точкой, а двумя... в любом случае хорошей практикой является перевод координат всех интересующих точек (зеленых и красных) в полярную систему координат с центром в зеленой точке (требуются афинные преобразования, ведь именно вокруг нее осуществляется вращение). После перевода в полярную систему координат (каждая точка имеет угол и расстояние от центра) осуществляется приращение углов (красных точек) на заданный. После этого осуществляется обратный перевод полярных координат точек в декартову систему. В целом решение выглядит так

Comment: Объект задан координатой красной точки, шириной и высотой

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Надеюсь, наведет на нужные мысли.</sub>

---

#### Поворот фигуры на угол на плоскости

```js
'use strict';
 
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
 
var canvas_context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
// Сместим начало координат в центр блока
canvas_context.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
 
// Фигуру будем задавать как массив точек,
// в нашем случае квадрат - четыре точки
var arr_t = [];
arr_t[0] = {x:-100, y:-100};
arr_t[1] = {x:100, y:-100};
arr_t[2] = {x:100, y:100};
arr_t[3] = {x:-100, y:100};
 
// Центр фигуры.
// Вокуг него будем осуществлять поворот
var t0 = {x:0, y:0};
 
// Угол поворота в градусах
var deg = 0;
 
// Создаем текущий массив точек
var arr_tt = [4];
 
// Задаем функцию обновления отображения
// с поворотом фигуры.
// Затем эту функцию надо будет вставить
// в переменную window.onload
function repaint() {
 
    // Сначала закрасим текущую фигуру
    canvas_context.lineWidth = 4; // rgba(255,255,255,1) - белый непрозрачный
    fillFigure(canvas_context, arr_tt, 'rgba(255,255,255,1)', true);
 
    // Теперь повернем исходную фигуру на угол
    // и перезапишем текущую фигуру
    for (var i = 0; i < arr_t.length; i++) {
        arr_tt[i] = rotateOnDegree(t0, arr_t[i], deg);
    }
 
    // Нарисуем новую фигуру
    canvas_context.lineWidth = 2; // rgba(0,0,0,0.5) - черный полупрозрачный
    fillFigure(canvas_context, arr_tt, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)', false);
 
    // И увеличим угол
    deg += 1;
}
 
// Рисуем фигуру по точкам из массива,
// опционально закрашиваем
function fillFigure(context, arr, color, fill) {
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.fillStyle = color;
 
    context.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 
        if (i == 0) {
            context.moveTo(arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
        } else {
            context.lineTo(arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
        }
    }
    context.closePath();
 
    if (fill) {
        context.fill();
    }
    context.stroke();
 
}
 
// Поворачиваем точку t(x,y) на угол (deg) относительно точки t0(x,y)
function rotateOnDegree(t0, t, deg) {
 
    var t_new = {};
 
    // Переводим угол поворота из градусов в радианы
    var rad = (Math.PI / 180) * deg;
 
    // И рассчитываем координаты новой точки по формуле
    t_new.x = t0.x + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.cos(rad) - (t.y - t0.y) * Math.sin(rad);
    t_new.y = t0.y + (t.x - t0.x) * Math.sin(rad) + (t.y - t0.y) * Math.cos(rad);
 
    // Возвращаем полученное значение
    return t_new;
}
 
// Устанавливаем интервал обновления отображения
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(repaint, 50);
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300" style="border: 1px solid gray">
    <p>Ваш браузер не поддерживает Canvas</p>
</canvas>
```